# AttributeError: 'map' obejct has no attribute 'index' (python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting above run time error, when I am trying to run an old python codebase into python3. The code looks like below.

```
index = map(lambda x: x[0], self.history).index(state)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Python 3 `map` doesn't return `list` but `map object` - see:

```
index = map(lambda x: x[0], [(1,2),(3,4)])
print( type(index) )
# <class 'map'>
```

you have to use `list()`

```
index = list(map(lambda x: x[0], self.history)).index(state)
```